# Qt 5.2 and Android Error

Tags: android, c++, qt, build

So after a few hours of struggling to set up my Qt so I can start with my first Android app I am still without luck.
I’ve gotten a VERY simple program (just to get all the settings right) to build properly but when I click the play button to run it, there is an error I cannot seem to solve. Here is the complete output when I press play:

```
22:16:45: Running steps for project Androidtest...
22:16:45: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
22:16:45: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe"
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
22:16:48: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
22:16:48: Starting: "mingw32-make" INSTALL_ROOT="D:\\RundownRiot\\Androidtest\\build-       Androidtest-Android_for_arm_GCC_4_6_Qt_5_2_0-Debug\\android-build" install
qtcreator_ctrlc_stub: Command line failed: mingw32-make INSTALL_ROOT="D:\\RundownRiot\\Androidtest\\build-Androidtest-Android_for_arm_GCC_4_6_Qt_5_2_0-Debug\\android-build" install
22:16:48: The process "mingw32-make" exited with code -1.
Error while building/deploying project Androidtest (kit: Android for arm (GCC 4.6, Qt 5.2.0))
When executing step 'Copy application data'
22:16:48: Elapsed time: 00:03.
```

The error is in line 6.

I read that sh.exe might be in the path variable but I don’t think its there, here is the value for path:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\CineForm\Tools;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;
C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;
C:\Android\AndroidSDK\sdk\tools;
C:\Android\AndroidSDK\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\bin;
```

I am using win7 32bit, Qt5.2 and Qt Creator 3.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I had more than 1 version of Qt installed. So I uninstalled Qt completely and only installed the latest version. That solved all my problems.

Comment: It actually worked for me. I cant believe it! I just uninstalled Qt and reinstalled the desired parts. It should be a logic explanation of what just had happened but uninstall/resintall is the fastest way to solve it. Thx